# Add a column in a dataframe which is conditioned on a multiple dataframes columns

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to add a new columns in the first dataframe called string_id, where I take **the string and distance from this first dataframe** and check

1. where the string matches in the second dataframe(columns = string_oldname')
2. the distance is between which range of the second dataframe and then take the string_id of the second dataframe.

**first df**:
| Timestamp           | **Distance**   | **String**   |
|:--------------------|:---------------|:-------------|
| 2021-09-01 00:11:37 | **0.414**      | **1**        |
| 2021-09-01 00:11:37 | 0.884          | 1            |
| 2021-09-01 00:11:37 | 1.354          | 1            |
| 2021-09-01 00:11:37 | 1.824          | 1            |

**2nd dataframe**:
| String_Id   | from    |      to | String_old_name   |
|:------------|:--------|--------:|:------------------|
| 1.1         | 8323.54 | 9272.67 | 1                 |
| 1.2         | 7353.54 | 8323.54 | 1                 |
| 1.3         | 6393.97 | 7353.54 | 1                 |
| 1.4         | 5444.51 | 6393.97 | 1                 |
| 1.5         | 4505.14 | 5444.51 | 1                 |
| 1.6         | 3545.57 | 4505.14 | 1                 |
| 1.7         | 2596.11 | 3545.57 | 1                 |
| 1.8         | 1687.00 | 2596.11 | 1                 |
| 1.9         | 848.68  | 1687    | 1                 |
| **1.10**    | **0.00**  |  **848.68** | **1**               |

For example: for the first row in the first dataframe, String = 1 and Distance = 0.414, so I check in the second dataframe for string_old_name = 1and the distance 0.414 is between which range  (0.00 and 848.68) so I take string_id 1.10!

Is it possible to add a column in the first dataframe with this complicated condition?

Thank you so much in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be expressed more elegantly, but this will get you where you need to go. Assuming the first dataframe is `df1` and the second is `df2` - First we merge the two dataframes on the `String` identifier, then we isolate the specific `String_Id` according to your conditions:

```py
df3 = df1.merge(df2, left_on='String', right_on='String_old_name')

df3.loc[(df3.Distance > df3['from']) & (df3.Distance < df3['to'])][['Distance', 'String_Id']].merge(df1, on='Distance')
```

This returns:

```py
Distance        String_Id   Timestamp   String
0   0.414       1.10    2021-09-01      1
1   0.884       1.10    2021-09-01      1
2   1954.120    1.8     2021-09-01      1
```

**Edit** 
For the function you wrote in your comment, simply make sure to get the values out of the Series you're returning. The following code will work:

```py
def find_string(row):
    cond_1 = (row["String"] == df2["String_old_name"])
    cond_2 = (row["Distance"] > df2["from"])
    cond_3 = (row["Distance"] < df2["to"])
    return df2[cond_1 & cond_2 & cond_3]["String_Id"].to_numpy()[0]

df1['string component'] = df1.apply(find_string, axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you so much @vtasca! This is exactly what I was looking for! I have one question do you know why the following code doesnt work: 
`code def find_string(row):
    
    cond_1 = (row["String"] == df2["String_old_name"])

    cond_2 = (row["Distance"] > df2["from"])
    cond_3 = (row["Distance"] < df2["to"])

    return df2[cond_1 & cond_2 & cond_3]["String_Id"]

df1['string component'] = df1.apply(find_string, axis=1)
`

Comment: @hania_w It doesn't work as expected because you're dealing with a Series and expecting values. Please see my updated answer.